# Question about compilation in Arabic tex

Tags: xetex, arabic, arabtex, arabxetex

I found this tex files but it gives me many errors (in \fancyhfoffset,\mainmatter,..): 
i compile with xelatex and texlive 2017

how to do ?

thank you

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{boxedminipage}
    \usepackage{slashbox} % PROBLEME
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{titlesec, color}
    \usepackage{fmultico}%PERMET MULTICOLUMN ARABE
    %%%----------------------------------------
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    %%%----------------------------------------
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    %%%----------------------------------------
    \makeatletter\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.8pt}{1cm}}
     \makeatother
    %%%----------------------------------------
     \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}
    %%%----------------------------------------
    \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Tahoma}
    \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Tahoma}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\bf\Large\headingfont}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\large\headingfont}
    \definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\headingfont}{\Huge\headingfont\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \topmargin=-2.25cm
    \usepackage{xeindex}%PACKAGE DE LINDEX
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \dominitoc
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%footnote a droite %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%         FOOTNOTE A DROITE AINSI QUE LE TRAIT    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\raggedleft\vspace*{-3pt}\rule{2in}{0.4pt}\vspace*{2.6pt}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \fancyhfoffset{0.1pt}%%%%% Trait du headings
    \rightfootnoterule
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\rhead[\normalsize\leftmark]{\normalsize\rightmark}
    %\lhead[\normalsize\rightmark]{\normalsize\leftmark}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%SINON LE FORMAT DU HEADING EST TROP  PETIT%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%ENTRE CROCHET PAGE PAIRE LAUTRE IMPAIRE
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%JUSQUAUX SOUS-SECTIONS
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%JUSQUAUX SECTIONS POUR MINITOC
    \setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bf\normalsize\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bf\normalsize\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bf\normalsize\leftmark}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COMMAND Polyglossia %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%REDEFINITION DES COMMANDES DE ARABTEX QUE NE CONNAIT PAS POLYGLOSSIA
    \renewcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\mbox{\RL{#1}}}
    %%%\newcommand{\textLR}[1]{\LR{\rmfamily #1}}
    \newcommand{\ARmbox}[1]{\mbox{\RL{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\textLR}[1]{\mbox{\LR{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\textRL}[1]{\mbox{\RL{#1}}}

    \title{\parbox{12cm}{
    %\includegraphics[width=2cm]{uko-logo.png} \\
    \begin{center}\Huge\bf\headingfont
    \rule{12cm}{4pt}
    \medskip
    {الجبر}
     \\[-4mm]
    \rule{12cm}{4pt}
    \end{center}
    \hfill\footnotesize
    تأليف: 
     \\[2cm]
     %{\Large الطبعة }
     \\[2cm]
     }}

    \author{ ترجمة:  كلية العلوم\\جامعة }
    \date{}
    \scrollmode
    %%%----------------------------------------
    \mainmatter
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \def\thepage{\arabic{page}}
    \renewcommand{\thethm}{\textbf{{\thechapter}.\textLR{\arabic{thm}}.\arabic{section}}}
    %%%--------------------------------------------
    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This template is a bit of a mess. First, do you have `slashbox.sty` installed? Next, change all occurrences of `\bf` to `bfseries`. Next, remove duplicate lines, such as `\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Tahoma}`. And if it’s not essential for demonstrating the problem, change Traditional Arabic to Amiri, since that’s in TeX Live, so that more of us will be able to test your example.

Comment: \bfseries or just bfseries @Thérèse

Comment: `\bfseries` (comments can’t be edited unless you notice the mistake quickly!).  `\bf` is a symptom of a *very* old template, so you should remove line by line until you have a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i stil have a problem with \fancyhfoffset

Comment: If you comment that line out, does the rest of the file compile?

Comment: it gives me error : undefined \thethm "\renewcommand{\thethm}{\textbf{{\thechapter}.\textLR{\arabic{thm}}.\arabic{section}}}"

Comment: Then comment out that line, and try again.  But I suspect the problem will be in the lines following `%REDEFINITION DES COMMANDES DE ARABTEX QUE NE CONNAIT PAS POLYGLOSSIA`, because `polyglossia` has been able to handle Arabic without such help for years now. Again, this looks like a very old template.  It would probably be easier to start with a new document and to add packages and new commands as needed.